# Current Person profile is not updated

Tags: android, google-plus

I am using Google+ api for Android and I am getting the profile info of signed user with [PlusClient.getCurrentPerson()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusClient.html#getCurrentPerson%28%29) function when everytime I connected to PlusClient(when onConnected() callback is called).

But when i update the Google+ profile, i still get the old profile information like old name and old photo. I tried disconnecting and connecting to PlusClient again and again but result is still old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible for the Android client to cache the user's profile information. To wipe the cache, do the following:

```
Open Android Settings -> <Select your app>
```

Click `Clear data`, click `Clear cache`.

This will make sure the cached profile data is removed.

If you want to trigger a cache update in a running application, performing a call that requires authorization sometimes will do the trick. An example would be making a call to [people.list](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people).